# Searching rows in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have strings of numbers not necessarily of the same length e.g.

`0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0`

`1,1,0,1`

`2,1,2,0,1,0`

I have imported these into a dataframe in R e.g. the above three strings would give the following three rows (which I shall call `df`):

[image]

I am looking to write some functions that will help me understand the data. As a starting point  - given a numeric vector `x` - I would like a 'process' `P` of establishing the number of rows which contain `x` as a subvector e.g. if `x = c(2,1)` then `P(x) = 2`, if `x = c(0,0,0)` then `P(x) = 1` and if `x = c(1,3)` then `P(x) = 0`. I have many more similar questions though I am hoping I will be able to take the logic from this question and work out some of the other stuff myself.

Comment: What if you made this into a character vector(s) and used regular expressions?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik definitely the way to go :)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik just a caution - converting floats to char may not do what is expected (rounding problems).  So long as the OP is just working with integers, regexp looks like a great solution.

Comment: You can avoid the costly conversion and subsequent regexing by matching the numbers directly. outer() is very useful here.

Comment: but `outer` is such a memory hog...

Comment: I changed my method to avoid outer, and compared with regexes. Apparently the regex solution is a lot faster than one would imagine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: The regex way would be:

```
match.regex <- function(x,data){
  xs <- paste(x,collapse="_")
  dats <- apply(data,1,paste,collapse="_")
  sum(grepl(xs,dats))
}


> match.regex(c(1),dat)
[1] 3
> match.regex(c(0,0,0),dat)
[1] 1
> match.regex(c(1,2),dat)
[1] 2
> match.regex(5,dat)
[1] 0
```

Surprisingly, this one is faster than other methods given here, and about twice as fast as my solution below, both on small and on big datasets. Regexes got pretty much optimized apparently :

```
> benchmark(matching(c(1,2),dat),match.regex(c(1,2),dat),replications=1000)
                       test replications elapsed relative 
2 match.regex(c(1, 2), dat)         1000    0.15      1.0 
1    matching(c(1, 2), dat)         1000    0.36      2.4
```

---

An approach that gives you the number immediately and works more vectorized, is the following:

```
matching.row <- function(x,row){
    nx <- length(x)
    sid <- which(x[1]==row)
    any(sapply(sid,function(i) all(row[seq(i,i+nx-1)]==x)))
}

matching <- function(x,data)
  sum(apply(data,1,function(i) matching.row(x,i)),na.rm=TRUE)
```

Here you first create a matrix with indices that move a window over a row of the same length as the vector you want to match. These windows are then checked against the vector. This approach is followed for every row, and the sum of the rows returning TRUE is what you want.

```
> matching(c(1),dat)
[1] 3
> matching(c(0,0,0),dat)
[1] 1
> matching(c(1,2),dat)
[1] 2
> matching(5,dat)
[1] 0
```

Comment: Very nice.  Be interesting to see a speed test between this and regexp.

Comment: ...and I suspect it will be even faster if you use `fixed = TRUE`. Also note that using `==` can still lead to floating error mismatches if the point was to allow for `numeric` comparisons.

Comment: @flodel `fixed=TRUE` doesn't gain you speed in this case. And numeric comparisons don't seem to make much sense in this context. You can use `all.equal()` in that case, but you have to strip attributes then to avoid problems there.

Comment: I actually expected this speed win, on the theory that regexp just matches byte patterns (my guess at how it works) while any numeric function has to do "stuff" with numbers and library lookups (again my guess at how it works).

Comment: thanks for you answer. out of interest why do you use `grepl` instead if `grep`? In the tests I've been doing to work out what's going on (I'm relatively new to R) I can't get `grep` and `grepl` to give different outputs, however when I use your code above replacing `grepl` with `grep` on my actual data frame the output is different.

Comment: on a related note how would I find the number of times a substring is contained within a string. it seems to me the outputs are `TRUE` and `FALSE` or `1` and `0`. more generally it would  be great if there was a process `P` which partitioned the strings depending on how many times they contained a substring e.g. using the table I originally posted `P(c(1,2))` would give `0:1, 1:2`, indicating that 1 of the strings didn't contain the substring 1_2 and two of the strings contained the substring 1_2 once. As another example `P(c(0))` would output `1:1, 2:1, 5:1`.

Comment: You can make that a new question, or adapt my second solution, or take a look at `gregexpr`

Comment: ok. i'll try the latter two first. good to know it's doable atleast. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You need to `apply` a function to the rows of your data:

```
apply(dat, MARGIN = 1, FUN = is.sub.array, x = c(2,1))
```

where `dat` is your data.frame and `is.sub.array` is a function that checks if `x` contained in a larger vector (in practice, the rows of your data.frame).

I am not aware of any available such `is.sub.array` function so here is how I would write it:

```
is.sub.array <- function(x, y) {
    j <- rep(TRUE, length(y))
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        if (i > 1) j <- c(FALSE, head(j, -1))
        j <- j & vapply(y, FUN = function(a,b) isTRUE(all.equal(a, b)),
                        FUN.VALUE = logical(1), b = x[i])
    }
    return(sum(j, na.rm = TRUE) > 0L)
}
```

(The advantage with using `all.equal` is that it can be used to compare `numeric` vectors, something that regular expressions won't be able to do.)

Here are a few examples:

```
apply(dat, 1, is.sub.array, x = c(1, 2))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
apply(dat, 1, is.sub.array, x = c(0, 0, 0))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
apply(dat, 1, is.sub.array, x = as.numeric(c(NA, NA)))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**Note**: `all.equal` is sensitive to your data type, so be careful to use an `x` with the same type as your data (integer or numeric).